# C# SerialPort WriteLine gets stuck

Tags: c#, arduino

I'm trying to send PWM target to Arduino Uno board via serial port via following C# code.

```
private SerialPort myPort= new SerialPort();       
myPort.BaudRate = 9600;
myPort.DtrEnable = true;
myPort.PortName = "COM3";
myPort.Open();
myPort.WriteLine("80");
```

Everytime the code gets stuck at the last line (WriteLine) without giving any errors. It just does not proceed further. What is causing it?

Comment: Set a WriteTimeout so it does not hang indefinitely. Try a Sleep between Open and WriteLine.  You may be just to fast for Arduino to correctly listen for what you send.

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend setting the Read timeout ([Microsoft API](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readtimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)), just in case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).